# Loading external URL in to WebView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview

Laoding external URL is having DialogBox with User Name and Password in to WebView. it gives me the error **Authorization Required**

URL "http://developer.xamarin.com:8081/api/todoitems"

[image]
I load many urls but not getting such error. But loading as above mention URL with Dialogbox for login it gives me error.

please help how I can display such url in WebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the credentials that are required for that page:

`myWebview.SetHttpAuthUsernamePassword(host, realm, username, password);`

[Xamarin Reference](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Webkit.WebView.SetHttpAuthUsernamePassword/p/System.String/System.String/System.String/System.String/)

Comment: if I dont know the credentials I just want to open diaologbox in webView

Comment: I don't think you can. You could detect a 401 response from the website and then display your own dialog to capture the details from the user, pass them back to the `SetHttpAuthUsernamePassword` method and refresh the page.

Comment: Use Sebastian's answer at https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30191/http-basic-authentication to detect the authorisation request and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_3_-_specialized_fragment_classes/#DialogFragment to create a dialog. Set the `SetHttpAuthUsernamePassword` in the click event.

Answer (score 1):

You can Create [Native WebView Renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/#Creating_the_Custom_Renderer_on_Android).
Add a WebViewClient to this webview renderer:

```
webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient ());
```

Create `MyWebViewClient` as follows with override [OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Webkit.WebViewClient.OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest/p/Android.Webkit.WebView/Android.Webkit.HttpAuthHandler/System.String/System.String/) :

```
class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    public override void OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest(Android.Webkit.WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, string host, string realm)
    {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(view.Context);

        dialog.SetContentView(/*Layout here*/);
        dialog.Show();

        //On submit Button Click from Layout set username and password:
        handler.Proceed(userName, password);
    }
}
```

The dialog is Layout in android project containing Username, password, submit and cancel fields. This you can create your own or take help from [some pages](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/).